Conditionally slice a pandas multiindex on specific level
For my given multi-indexed DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(12),
    index=[
        [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8],
        [1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2],
    ]
)

            0
1 1  1.667692
  2  0.274428
2 1  0.216911
3 1 -0.513463
4 1 -0.642277
  2 -2.563876
5 1  2.301943
  2  1.455494
6 1 -1.539390
  2 -1.344079
7 2  0.300735
8 2  0.089269

I would like to slice it such that I keep only rows where second index level contains BOTH 1 and 2
            0
1 1  1.667692
  2  0.274428
4 1 -0.642277
  2 -2.563876
5 1  2.301943
  2  1.455494
6 1 -1.539390
  2 -1.344079

How can I do this?

Another possible solution, which is based on the following:

df.groupby(level=0) groups the dataframe by the first level of the index.

filter(lambda x: set(x.index.get_level_values(1)) == {1, 2}) checks if the second level of the index for each group contains both 1 and 2,  and retains only the groups that meet this condition.


df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: set(x.index.get_level_values(1)) == {1, 2})

Output:
            0
1 1 -1.085631
  2  0.997345
4 1 -0.578600
  2  1.651437
5 1 -2.426679
  2 -0.428913
6 1  1.265936
  2 -0.866740


This is an alternative to the other answers that should be more performant (ideally by skipping the groupby, and using pandas' own set-like methods): Get the values at level 0 where level 1 is both 1 & 2, and index the dataframe with it:
mi = df.index
base = mi.get_level_values(0)
filter1=mi.get_locs([slice(None), 1])
filter2=mi.get_locs([slice(None), 2])
indexer=base[filter1].intersection(base[filter2])
df.loc[indexer]

            0
1 1  0.395119
  2 -0.358966
4 1  0.023952
  2  0.976810
5 1  0.217600
  2 -1.385707
6 1  1.334745
  2 -0.018886

If you have more values, you can use a comprehension.

I like your solution, @sammywemmy. However, I suspect it is missing to define base.

You could convert the Multindex to_frame to be able to perform a groupby.transform with set.issubset to generate a Series for boolean indexing:
out = df[df.index.to_frame().groupby(0)[1].transform({1, 2}.issubset)]

NB. if you want exactly (not at least) {1, 2}, use lambda x: set(x) == {1, 2} as function in transform.
If you need to perform this in chained commands:
df.loc[lambda x: x.index.to_frame().groupby(0)[1].transform({1, 2}.issubset)]

Output:
            0
1 1 -1.017357
  2  0.869500
4 1 -1.348415
  2  0.625116
5 1  0.708617
  2  0.438953
6 1  0.632509
  2  0.693872

Intermediate:
df.index.to_frame().groupby(0)[1].transform({1, 2}.issubset)

1  1     True
   2     True
2  1    False
3  1    False
4  1     True
   2     True
5  1     True
   2     True
6  1     True
   2     True
7  2    False
8  2    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

